# RethinkDB: Getting random documents for each category

Tags: database-performance, rethinkdb

I have a table with `~8000 quiz questions`.
They are divided in `25 categories`.
Each category has a attribute `max_questions` which tells me how many questions i have to pick `randomly` to generate a quiz.

e.g

```
Category 1 -> 2 questions
Category 2 -> 3 questions
Category 3 -> 1 question
```

I came up with a solution, but i takes approx. 2 seconds to perform.

```
r.table('categories').pluck('id', 'max_questions').orderBy('id').run(conn, function(err, cursor) {
    if(err) return next(new Error(err.msg));

    cursor.toArray(function(err, categories) {
        if(err) return next(new Error(err.msg));

        async.concat(categories, function(category, callback) {
            r.table('questions').filter({category_id: category.id }).sample(category.max_questions).run(conn, callback);
        }, function(err, questions) {
            if(err) return next(new Error(err.msg));
            res.json(questions);
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a faster way to retrieve the questions with RethinkDB? Making 25 requests and calling 25 times `.sample()` for one quiz doesn't sound good to me.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be much faster if you do it all in one query rather than making multiple requests to the database. Here's a single query that's more or less equivalent to what you wrote:

```
categories.map(function (doc) {
    return doc.merge(
        {"questions":
           questions
           .filter({category_id:doc("id")})
           .sample(doc("max_questions"))
           .coerceTo("ARRAY")})
})
```

Notice I've bound the tables to variables here so `categories` is bound to `r.table("categories")`.

Comment: This was exactly what i wanted. It performs now with 530ms. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, if you want to make this even faster you can create an index the category_id field.

Comment: I changed the .filter({category_id:cat('id')}) method to .getAll(cat('id'), {index: 'category_id'}) and got massive performance improvements. With rethinkdb 1.12.1 filter() took ~ 1.2seconds, getAll() only ~ 150ms. Any ideas why?

Comment: `filter` requires reading every single document in the table of disk while `getAll` only needs to read the documents it returns (and maybe a few others) off disk. Indexes are designed to be a way to make filter operations much faster.